# Get start of week from Calendar app

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the start of week setting in the Calendar app of the device? I'm well aware of the locale-based approach in the `Calendar` class (or replacements like ThreeTen or Joda), that's not what I'm after. I'd like to allow the user to change the starting day and if possible, I wouldn't like to provide my own preference setting but use the presumably system wide setting already present inside the stock Calendar app.

I tried to look in `CalendarContract` but that only has actual events, not basic settings like this.

Comment: Do you want to *get* or *set* the starting day of the week?

Comment: Only to get it (first word of the title ;-) ).

Comment: Sure, I got confused by *I'd like to allow the user to change the starting day* part

Comment: Okay, so you want to access Calendar app settings, basically? I don't think this is possible unless Calendar app exposes it somehow. But then you probably shouldn't rely on other app on the device, sice someone could not have it installed

Comment: Yes, basically. The quoted part in broader context: yes, I'd like to allow the user to change, no matter what's stored in the locale defaults in Android. But I don't necessarily wanted to incorporate it into my own app. Just like the user can decide what date or time display format to use (even if it doesn't match the locale defaults), and my app can simply *get* that information, I was hoping for something similar to exist for the start of week, so that the user can set it in Calendar, but that setting to be something system-wide that I can *get* similarly. Sad if it doesn't exists...

Comment: I think it's okay - just let the user define starting week in your app, or just go with locale default.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did now. I only had to create a special preference widget for it (because I don't want to supply and localize the day names myself, of course, I read them from the system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of an answer and a finished question: there seems to be no way. I had to implement my own setting in my app's preferences.